# Python FuelSDK 1.3.0 no longer working?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, marketingcloudapi

I had to revert from python FuelSDK 1.3 to 0.9, because as of around 2pm Eastern on 3-Mar-2021, the code was failing on authentication, the server response was failing the JSON parser.  Anyone else experience this?